# How can I center and scale a `mindmap`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, mindmaps

I've been trying to define a `mindmap` that covers the entire `a4paper` page and that is centered.
The result is unsatisfying at the moment:
[image]
MWE:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
 
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}  % Mindmap drawing library 
\usepackage[left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\input{L1.tex}

\end{document}
```

`L1.tex`

```
\vspace*{\fill} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        mindmap,
        concept color = blue!40,
        every node/.style = {concept},
        grow cyclic,
        level 1/.append style = {
            concept color = blue!30,
            level distance = 4.5cm,
            sibling angle = 120
        },
        level 2/.append style = {
            concept color = blue!20,
            level distance = 3cm,
            sibling angle = 45
        }
    ]
    %Nodo principale
    \node [concept] at (current page.center) {Machine Learning}
        %Definizione
        child[grow=30]{
            node {Programma che:}
                child[grow= 30] {
                    %Esperienza
                    node {Apprende dall'esperienza $E$}
                        child[grow=30]{node {Tipi di dati}}
                        child[grow=150]{node {Come elaboro i dati}}
                        child[grow=270]{node {Come i dati vengono usati}}
                }
                child[grow=150] {
                    %Tasks
                    node {Risolve un problema $T\in$ Tasks}
                        child[grow=45]{node {Problema da risolvere}}
                        child[grow=135]{node {Rappresenta output atteso}}
                }
                child[grow=270] {
                    %Performance
                    node {Performance $P$ migliora con $E$}
                        child[grow=225]{node {definisce bontà di $f$}}
                        child[grow=315]{node {dipende dal tipo di $T$}}
                }
        }
        %Classi dei Tasks
        child[grow=150]{
            node {Classi di $T$}
                child[grow=30] {node {Recupero delle informazioni}}
                child[grow=90] {node {Classificazione}}
                child[grow=150] {node {Sistemi di Raccomandazione}}
                child[grow=210] {node {Riconoscimento di modelli}}
                child[grow=270] {node {Predizione di eventi}}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
```

There could be tons of errors of related to my inexperience with `mindmap` package.
I hope that someone could give me a hint!

Comment: To center the mindmap, have you tried putting a `\begin{center}`/`\end{center}` around your `tikzpicture` environment? Did the trick for me

Comment: In addition, for the figure to occupy more space on the page, would putting your tikzpicture environment in a `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{<your tikzpicture>}` work for you?

Comment: I had some problems using `center`, so that's why I asked here. I forgot to mention it, my fault. That could be just a problem of mine, but I'm still trying to get out of it @KersouMan Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) To achieve the horizontal centering use `\begin{figure}\centering\begin{tikzpicture} ...`

(2) To enlarge the mindmap evenly in both directions, use `\scalebox{<factor>}`

[image: b]

This is the file `L1.tex`. (Used `\usepackage[left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm,showframe]{geometry}` in `main.tex` to show the margins)

```
%% File L1.tex

\vspace*{\fill} 

\begin{figure}[ht!] % added <<<<<<<<<<<
\centering % added <<<<<<<<<<<
\scalebox{1.5}{% % added <<<<<<<<<<<
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    mindmap,
    concept color = blue!40,
    every node/.style = {concept},
    grow cyclic,
    level 1/.append style = {
        concept color = blue!30,
        level distance = 4.5cm,
        sibling angle = 120
    },
    level 2/.append style = {
        concept color = blue!20,
        level distance = 3cm,
        sibling angle = 45
    }
    ]
    %Nodo principale
    \node [concept] at (current page.center) {Machine Learning}
    %Definizione
    child[grow=30]{
        node {Programma che:}
        child[grow= 30] {
            %Esperienza
            node {Apprende dall'esperienza $E$}
            child[grow=30]{node {Tipi di dati}}
            child[grow=150]{node {Come elaboro i dati}}
            child[grow=270]{node {Come i dati vengono usati}}
        }
        child[grow=150] {
            %Tasks
            node {Risolve un problema $T\in$ Tasks}
            child[grow=45]{node {Problema da risolvere}}
            child[grow=135]{node {Rappresenta output atteso}}
        }
        child[grow=270] {
            %Performance
            node {Performance $P$ migliora con $E$}
            child[grow=225]{node {definisce bontà di $f$}}
            child[grow=315]{node {dipende dal tipo di $T$}}
        }
    }
%   %Classi dei Tasks
    child[grow=150]{
        node {Classi di $T$}
        child[grow=30] {node {Recupero delle informazioni}}
        child[grow=90] {node {Classificazione}}
        child[grow=150] {node {Sistemi di Raccomandazione}}
        child[grow=210] {node {Riconoscimento di modelli}}
        child[grow=270] {node {Predizione di eventi}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{\fill}
```

Comment: This worked totally fine for me: thanks you for the answer!!